# Consider the functions $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x|x|$. (Linear independence)

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $S = [f(x), g(x)]$ is linearly independent in the real vector space $C([−1, 1])$. However, that it is linearly dependent in $C([0, 1])$ and $C([−1, 0])$.

I tried using the Wronskian, but it didn't seem to work. I don't know how to establish the different intervals using this method (or if it is even possible to do so).

Comment: "establish the different intervals" what do you mean?

Comment: Hint:  simplify $x|x|$ on, say, $[0,1]$.

Comment: When you use the Wronskian, you simply calculate the determinant. The different intervals are not taken into account. I actually don't know if you can use this method to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we must know that $${\mid x \mid}=\begin{array}{cc}
  \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      -x &  x< 0 \\
      x & x \ge 0 \\
    \end{array}
\end{array}$$
Now since we have $$ f(x)=x^2 \ and \ g(x)=x\mid x \mid $$
Case 1 we have: $$ ax^2+bx\mid x \mid=0 =>if \ x>0 \ we \ have  \ (a+b)x^2=0=>a=-b  \ so  \ f(x) \ and \ g(x) \ are \ linear \ dependent $$
Case 2 we have: $$ ax^2+bx\mid x \mid=0 =>if \ x<0 \ we \ have  \ (a-b)x^2=0=>a=b  \ so  \ f(x) \ and \ g(x) \ are \ linear \ dependent $$

Now case 3 is a combined case between case 1 and 2 we have that:$$ if \ x \in(-\epsilon;\epsilon) \ with 
\ \epsilon>0 \ then \ if \ we  \ use \ case1: a=-b=>for \ case 2 \ we \ have\ : 2ax^2=0 \ which \ is \ true \iff a=0 => linear  \ independece   
$$

$$
Same \ if \ we \ use \ case2: a=b=>for \ case 1 \ we \ have\ : 2ax^2=0 \ which \ is \ true \iff a=0 => linear  \ independece 
$$

Comment: MathJax tips: 1) Not everything has to be inside `$$ $$`, you can use `$ $` to have maths displayed inline. 2) You can use `\text{}` inside `$ $` to display text, well, as text. Still, this amount of text should be written normally, this is just too difficult to read. 3) You can use environment `\begin{cases} \end{cases}` to properly display piecewise defined function. 4) Use `\implies` or `\Rightarrow` instead of `=>`. 5) Use `|x|` instead of `\mid x \mid`. 6) Consult our [MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

In the interval $[0,1]$, we essentially have $f(x)=g(x)$, while in the interval $[-1,0]$ we have $f(x)=-g(x)$.